# Concept of hymen breakage of vagina is sign of good character

Tags: hadith, nikah, sharia, tafseer, women

What does islam and hadis say about breakage of Hymen of a virgin girl? Is it a symbol of good character or nobel sign of virgin girls? A girl of good character should have it? A girl is real religious girl and the Hymen proved that. Bad character girls wdnt have it?

Is it allowed by islam to ask from girls that why her Hymen hasnt broken?to say her bad character on this proof is halal or permissible in islam?

Explain with sharah reference and hadis please.
Some girls have intact hymen and sometimes your hymen is not broken at wedding night so, can you please explain with sharah reference that islam says that only good, religious women would have it . Otherwise those girls that dont cover her heads and involved in unethical deeds or not so religious, their hymen would be broken so women of such type wouldnt have it. What does Islam say about intact hymen and broken hymen having women character? Clarify both with ahadis and sharah?

Comment: Why the tag islamic-scholar?

Answer (score 4):

It's a sign of Jahilliyah (ignorance) when you see people judging people's moral uprightness based upon something physical i.e., the body. Allah (ﷻ) always spoke of "deeds". Suspicions based upon things like the hymen are unfounded in Islam. - The Sharii evidence is the lack of evidence of any judgement based on hymen. Whatever is accceptable as evidence was detailed to us in the Qur'an/Sunnah.

> أفحكم الجاهلية يبغون ومن أحسن من الله حكما لقوم يوقنون
>
> Do they then seek the judgement of (the Days of) Ignorance? - Qur'an 5:50

A woman of bad character will have many bad signs; and a woman with good character will have many good signs. (*Note: If a person cannot tell the difference then perhaps he/she needs to brush up on Islamic morality*). Hymen isn't a sign. For good women, it can be tore with non-sex related activities. For bad women, nowadays there are medical procedures to restore the hymen which they resort to; so you never really know.

In conclusion: This is not an Islamic criteria for moral uprightness of a woman.